# different services handling in 1.0.5 and 1.2.19

Tags: angularjs

I'm upgrading an application from angular 1.0.5 to 1.2.19 and I can't get my head around the following issue.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mszrnyi/p4dgt/4/) demonstrates the old behaviour. Check the console output and compare it with the new angular version in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mszrnyi/p4dgt/3/).

We are using coffee script so removing the return value is an option or even better

```
return this
```

at the end works. But this seems to be the wrong approach and I would like to understand why it's acting differently to find the best approach to rewrite stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why that worked in the old version of Angular but generally speaking in JavaScript when  you define a constructor you should either return undefined or `this`. I came across this post that talks about what can happen when you return something else: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2522-providing-a-return-value-in-a-javascript-constructor.htm

If you're using coffeescript though you can just create a class for your service. Take a look at this article for more info on using a class as a service http://alxhill.com/blog/articles/angular-coffeescript/

Comment: Great thanks! That's what I thought as well but I totally don't understand why it was working before. Anyway I'll rewrite the services to a more coffee script like structure. Here is another great example: https://gist.github.com/bhollis/8469859